# attach image from an app to gmail and share

Tags: android

I want to share my image from app only using `gmail`.
Here is my piece of code:

```
if (id == R.id.menu_item_share) {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,`enter code here`
            new String[] { "bipush.osti@gmail.com" });
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "compose mail");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, targetUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));

}
```

[image: i am getting all the sharing app, i want gmail to open with my image attached to it]

How do I modify my codes

Comment: You can open only mail client using ACTION_SENDTO constant.

Answer (score 0):

This method allow you to share the data for a single application.

```
      public void share(String nameApp, String imagePath, String message) {
        try {
            List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");
           share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,`enter code here`
            new String[] { "bipush.osti@gmail.com" });
          share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
          share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "compose mail");
            List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager()
                    .queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
            if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
                for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                    Intent targetedShare = new Intent(
                            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    targetedShare.setType("image/jpeg"); // put here your mime
                                                            // type
                    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(
                            nameApp)
                            || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(
                                    nameApp)) {
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                                "Sample Photo");
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                                Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)));
                        targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                    }
                }
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
                        targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                        targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
                startActivity(chooserIntent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("VM",
                    "Exception while sending image on" + nameApp + " "
                            + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

For example you can share the image for the `gmail` by using.

```
File filePath = new File("your image path");
share("gmail",filePath.toString(),"your comment");
```

you can also share to other application by simply changing the name.

```
share("facebook",filePath.toString(),"your comment");
share("twitter",filePath.toString(),"your comment");
```

Comment: so to attach an image file, i needa write the file name or the path?

Comment: the required image is not gettiing attached

Comment: it requires the file's absolutePath

Answer (score 0):

Try to setType `message/rfc822` instead of `image/png`

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the package name of the application which you want to handle it. To send it through the Gmail app add the below line

```
sharingIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
```